How to change the timezone for Alexa
I have shifted countries a few months ago.  When I ask for the brief in the morning, it still gives the weather for my old city.  I have changed the time zone in the Alexa app.  I have changed the following, but this has not fixed it. It sort of half knows where I am as the ads are a mixture of the old country and the new country, when I play TuneIn.

Alexa
Settings
Alexa App Settings
Time Zone and Device Location

How do I change the time zone and location for Alexa?

You say your problem is that it gives you the weather for the old city, and then you talk about the timezone. Don't you want to change the default city instead?

@jcaron, Quite right, I had set the location as well, which it fetches from GPS.  Updated the question.

Is it not somehow linked to your Amazon account? (I'm really not familiar with Alexa, if that doesn't show!)

The process turns out to be a bit quirky and convoluted.  It turns out that (not totally unexpectedly), the Alexa App  settings do not apply to the devices.  You have to alter the settings on each device as well.

Go to Settings

Select Device Settings

Scroll to the bottom (especially if you have a lot of devices for Automation) and select the Alexa Device

Press Settings (Gear icon)


You can change the time zone here if required.

You can also change Device Location by selecting it.

You are presented with a map.  But this does not work because you are in the wrong country!!

Type in a character and only then do you see Advanced Search


Press Advanced Search

You see the following screen, change the Country.

You can enter the address here, but its not checked.

It is easier to back to the previous screen and enter/pick the correct address.



